# Video Streaming from phone to internet visitors, with a few seconds delay & review

Tags: java, android, html, video-streaming, broadcasting

I need to set up a web-based streaming video of an event.

The unit taking the video would most likely be a smartphone
(or possibly real video-camera somehow tied to a computer)

What I need is

- A way to capture the video and compress and transmit over the internet.
  (and preferably record in full quality it as well, but that is optional)
- Display the video to end users on the website with some seconds of delay.
  (plugins or downloads are acceptable, but not optimal)
- Display the video to the moderator who gets to see the video live with no added delay.
  (in charge of immediately noticing any 'bad things happening')
- Provide the moderator the ability to interrupt the transmission to end users.
  (obviously, so if anything did go wrong, the end user wouldn't see it)

Before I ask advice on how to write the code, First, Do you think it would be better to

1. Use an online service for the whole ordeal. (this would only work if the moderator interrupt was available, I didn't find any, but maybe there is one)
2. Use some pre-built modules or apps that handle these, and the connect them.
3. Develop these components ourselves, which we are equipped to do using Java.
4. A combination of 2 and 3. (one example would be, write an app for the Android, a plugin for the Player, and then write our own moderator interrupt, brodcast and delay code server-side.)

Can you help me decide which direction I should take, and the pros or cons of them?

Comment: I would *strongly* recommend that you divide this into separate questions. Only one of your four bullets has anything to do with Android; the rest has to do with a Web site and client, which is not included in your tags. Also, bear in mind that "Questions asking us to recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it."

Comment: Thanks, any help on communicating this properly is appreciated. I made an edit, how is this?